# Is there any way to solve image problem on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am working on one website on WordPress and I can't see any images and that is not an issue that I can see images on localhost and can't see it online.
It suddenly stops showing the images and displaying this notice.
I am getting this **notice:** ob_end_flush(): failed to send buffer of zlib output compression (0).
I have removed this error but still, I can't get images on my website.
If I try to upload a new image(s) it shows a broken image.
Please help to get all the images back on my site.

Thank You.

Comment: Hey, Is if possible then check images are exists on the upload folder which you are looking for and also check on localhost images are already there in folder for which you have path given

Comment: Under wp-admin->settings->media what is the path?

Comment: @NiketJoshi Yes images are on the uploaded folder but it's broken over there also, If I select an image I just can see the name of that images and I am working on live site so there is no need to check localhost. When I started working on it I can upload the images and I can see also.

Thank You.

Comment: @HowardE I can't see any path over there. I can just see the Images size option.
Some of the menu icons are also missing. If I hover my mouse on it than I can see the sub-menu options.

Thank You.

Comment: @Kaushal, Check the path of image by inspect element in browser, in that path contain LIVE server URL or localhost URL

Comment: @NiketJoshi It is showing me this error: The requested URL /wp-content/plugins/webp-express/wod/webp-on-demand.php was not found on this server. 
Can you tell me how to solve it?

Thank You.

Comment: @Kaushal, Please disable that plugin for a moment and then test the site

Comment: @NiketJoshi Thank You for the advice but I got the problem and solved it and images are back on the site. By mistake one plugin was deleted and that's why I am facing these issues.

Comment: @Kaushal, most welcome mate, please flag comment if comment is helpful to you